# Daterangepicker change angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, datepicker

I have a date range picker and I need to add a listener everytime i change the range of the values so i sent the startDate and endDate in my url to a restapi and then make a query to my databse with that valeus and get new rows.

My problem is with the listener.. I need something like "onChange" when i set new dates.

View:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-3 mb0" ng-if="timerange == 'custom'">
                        <div class="row">
                            <label class="col-sm-3 control-label pt7">Custom</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                                <input type="text" id="customrange" name="customrange" ng-model="parent.customrange" ng-change="applyOptions()" class="form-control" ui-jq="daterangepicker" ui-options="{format: 'YYYY/MM/DD',startDate: '{{startdate}}',endDate: '{{enddate}}', maxDate:'{{enddate}}'}" />                                
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Controller:

```
var rangeSelector = document.getElementsByTagName('select')[1]; //1h 24h 1w custom
if(rangeSelector.value == 'custom'){
    var datePicker = document.getElementById("customrange").getAttribute('ui-options');

    var split = datePicker.split(",");  

 var startDate = split[1].split(': ')[1].replace(/["']/g, '');
   var endDate = split[2].split(': ')[1].replace(/["']/g, '');

if (startDate !== undefined) {
    url += '&startDate='+startDate;
}
if (endDate !== undefined) {
    url += '&endDate='+endDate;
```

}

i tried 2 optiuons but i cant get into that code when i put a breakpoint on it..

```
$scope.$watch("customrange", function() {
  console.log("I've changed : ");
});
```

and

```
rangeSelector.addEventListener("change", function(e){
    if(rangeSelector.value == "custom"){
        e.preventDefault();
        customrange = document.getElementById("customrange");
        customrange.addEventListener("change", function(){
             startEndDate = controllerScope.getStartEndTimestamps();
        });
      }
}, false);
```

Anyone can help me please??

[Image of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9YY0.png)

Answer (score 0):

Updated:

The problem is that your $watch is not checking the correct model.

Your $watch should be called as follows:

```
$scope.$watch("parent.customrange", function(newValue, oldValue) {
 console.log("I've changed : ");
});
```

To watch the object "parent":

```
$scope.$watch("parent", function(newValue, oldValue) {
  console.log("I've changed : ");
}, true);
```

The true sets the optional objectEquality check.

[Angular $watch Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch):

> When objectEquality == true, inequality of the watchExpression is determined according to the angular.equals function. To save the value of the object for later comparison, the angular.copy function is used. This therefore means that watching complex objects will have adverse memory and performance implications.

Comment: I tried that and it console.log when i cange tabs.. when i pick dates and apply nothing happens.. it doenst log anything

Comment: Try  watching "parent.customrange".  As you are now watching a field of the object you can remove the "true".

Comment: Have updated to correct answer. Please select as answer. Cheers

Comment: Sorry but it only shows the alert when pages opens when i press apply nothing happen...

Comment: Have a look at the docs again: `The listener fn is called asynchronously (via $evalAsync) to initialize the watcher.` What this means is that the the listener logic will be called on load. I can't see the apply functionality but make sure it is changing the `parent.customrange` model. As this is what we are watching

Comment: I need when i press apply to have the  data changed.. i cant get the data understand ... is like a change on the input.. the parent is a dropdown.. it has custom value and dont change